# If a class implements addition and concatenation, which magic methods should be used for what?

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

I have a class that is basically an optimised generator (like `range`). It implements `__getitem__`, `__iter__` and `__contains__`. It also needs to implement addition of its items (immutable numbers) with that of another instance:

```
def addition(self, other):
    for x in zip(self, other):
        yield sum(x)
```

and concatenation of two instances:

```
def concatenation(self, other):
    yield from self
    yield from other
```

(The real methods return instances of subclasses that implement this in their `__iter__` method, with necessary optimisations to reduce the complexity of `__contains__` where possible, but I simplified it for the example.)

Types such as `str`, `list` and `tuple` implement concatenation with `__add__`. Types such as `int` and `float` implement addition with `__add__`. I can't implement both with `__add__`.

What magic methods should I use for addition and concatenation if a class implements both?

Comment: Every magic method is mapped to one single operator. If you want to override `+`  you have to handle the exceptions inside the function `__add__` manually, in order to handle all the situations.

Comment: @Kasramvd  I can't use `+` for both addition and concatenation because that causes ambiguities. I'm asking what I _should_ use for each.

Comment: It depends on your object's entity at the first place. If your object is an iterator of  numerical types it's better to use `+` addition and for concatenation use a regular method name `concatenate` or `chin`.

Comment: @Kasramvd That answers the question. If you have time, perhaps you could write it up as an answer.

Comment: Downvoter: I'd _really_ like to know how I can improve this question.